# When should we detach a Firestore Listener in Vue JS?

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a Web Application using **Google's Firestore** and **VueJS** and i am setting up around 3 real-time listeners inside the Vuex Store and a few more inside other components.

Right now, i am enabling the ones in the store when the application starts and detach them only when the user logs out. Also, i am not detaching at all the ones that i am creating separately in other components.

When i look at my Firestore's DB Usage i see that the peaks of my Snapshot Listeners are pretty high. A lot more than i should have, as i am the only one using the app now.

[image]

My question is: 
**When should we detach the listeners?** Because it's pretty obvious that i am doing something wrong.

Thank you!

Comment: The Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore are two separate databases. Please only mark your question with the relevant tag, not with both.

Comment: You should detach a listener when your app no longer needs the data from that listener. Without seeing what listeners you attach, there's really not a lot more we can say.